# Is a constructor called when passing objects as an argument?

Tags: c++, constructor, parameter-passing

I'm trying to compile an old code that I had to work with C++ inheritance. I've been fixing things for a while but I surrendered with this error:

```
class Operation{
    public:
    char *op;
    //Operation();
    Operation(char op[]){
    (*this).op = op;
    }
};

class Param : Operation{
    public:
    int value;

    Param(char op[], int value) : Operation(op){

    (*this).op=op;
    (*this).value=value;
    }

    int getValue(){
    return this->value;
    }

};


class MyBase{
    public:
    int valuea;
    int valueb;
    Operation operation;

    MyBase(int a, int b, Operation* op){
    valuea=a;
    valueb=b;
    operation=*op;
    }

    Operation* getSum(){};

    Operation* getRest(){};
};

class MyExtend : public MyBase{
    public:

    Param* getSum(){
        Param pam=new Param(this->valuea+this->valueb,"add");
        return pam;
    }

    Param* getRest(){
        Param pam=new Param(this->valuea-this->valueb,"rest");
        return pam;
    }
};

class Exec{

public int static main(args[] params){
    MyExtend ext=new MyExtend(6,4);
    cout << ext.getSum().getValue() << endl;
    cout << ext.getRest().getValue() << endl;
    return 0;
}

};
```

I'm focusing on the error at

MyBase(int a, int b, Operation* op){

that is:

error: no matching function for call to 'Operation::Operation()'

I'm surprised because it looks like its checking for the default constructor of Operation. If I overload the default constructor it works, but I don't understand why. Doen't matter if I pass Operation by value or reference. May you give me some hints about this functionality? I wasn't able to find a consistent response. Please, ignore the following errors as I'm working on them.

All the best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MyBase` contains a member named `operation` that is of type `Operation` and is neither a pointer or a reference, so that member must be constructed by the compiler when `MyBase` is constructed. That member is not being initialized in the (non-existent) initialization list for the `MyBase` constructor, so the compiler will attempt to default-construct it; however, `Operation` does not have a default constructor, hence the error.

A possible fix would be to rework the constructor of `MyBase` to use an initialization list, like so:

```
class MyBase
{
  public:
    int valuea;
    int valueb;
    Operation operation;

    MyBase(int a, int b, Operation* op)
    : valuea(a)
    , valueb(b)
    , operation(*op) { }
};
```

But note that—as it stands—this will rely on the *default* (i.e., compiler-supplied) copy-constructor, which may not do what you want, so you should probably supply an explicit copy ctor.

Comment: Understood. A powerful answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: +1, but I don't think a copy constructor by itself would be an improvement here. `Operation` is a base class of `Param`, and the OP will almost certainly want `Param` objects stored in `operation`. A smart pointer type would probably be a better choice, which does not necessarily need to make a copy of `*op`.

Comment: I'm using Code::Blocks as my IDE because it provides many compilers but at runtime I get: mingw32-g++.exe  -o bin\Release\Tests.exe obj\Release\Exec.o   -s  
c:/program files/codeblocks/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):main.c:(.text.startup+0xa7): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
1 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds)

Comment: I know this is not related, but do you know what may happening?

Comment: My main function is: int main( int argc, const char* argv[] ) and I'm compiling a console app, not a GUI.